# Concatenation of String and params in mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have searched for this and `+` and `$` won't work. I wan't to concatenate `%` with `#search` param in mybatis select query. I want to achieve this in mybatis XML config not service(Java)...

I have this query

```
<select id="carriersDataTable" parameterType="map" resultType = "carrier">
        SELECT 
        carrierId
        name, 
        prefix,
        country, 
        status,
        isdirect as direct
        FROM carriers
        WHERE name LIKE '%' + #{search} + '%' AND Status != -1 AND IF(''=#{status}, 1, Status = #{status})
        ORDER BY name
        LIMIT #{startIndex}, #{fetchSize}
    </select>
```

I have tried `LIKE '%' + #{search} + '%'` and `LIKE ${%#{search}%}` both won't work

Answer (score 3):

Try the built-in string concatenation function in the DB, e.g.

```sql
LIKE CONCAT('%', #{search}, '%')
```

For MySQL

Comment: It works. However, '%' || #{search} || '%' doesn't work.

Comment: @ParkJongBum AFAIK the `||` operator is Oracle specified.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `'%' || #{search} || '%'`
It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the % in sql you must use the $ symbol

```
'%' + '${search}' + '%'
```

keep in mind thant using ${} expose your query to sql injection so you must escape the search string properly in java code

Comment: Thanks for reply but your solution gives `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+  + '%' AND Status != -1 AND IF(''='', 1, Status = '')' at line 4] with root cause` and by the way you are right it would lead to SQL injection and that's why its better to handle this in service layer...

Comment: you are right, I forgot two ' in my response, I made the correction

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="selectBlogsLike" resultType="Blog">
  <bind name="pattern" value="'%' + _parameter.getTitle() + '%'" />
  SELECT * FROM BLOG
  WHERE title LIKE #{pattern}
</select>
```

Documentation: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

There were two properties - personId and personNickName

> personId javaType is java.math.BigInteger, value is eg. 123
>
> personNickName javaType is String, value is eg. 'MACK'

So, in `mybatis` I need the concatenation in where clause of query '123MACK'

```
Select * From 
From PersonTable 
Where personUniqueValue = cast(#{personId} as varchar) + #{personNickName}
```

Hope it will help someone.